# Why does Virtual Box delete/hide my .vdi files?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, vdi

I tried to to download and set up a virtual machine in virtual box with the Python [Kivy vdi](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B112pXITp0hJU3dJb25hbWJ3RHM/view) for creating kivy android apps with buildozer. My problem is that the default disk space on the vdi isn't that big (6 - 8 Gbit), so there is not enough space for me to install all the tools I need. When I tried to manually increase the disk size [with this yt tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Aqx-VHv2_k&list=PLUiU6Y62RNSeWK9tgDZVwdQk1ZN-sBvxJ&index=75&t=0s) and [this website](https://dev.to/ech0server/how-to-resize-a-virtualbox-linux-vdi-disk-under-windows-host-2d1p) I mentioned that **the .dvi file was missing** in my "VirtualBox VMs" folder. I don't know if the vdi file was deleted or is just hidden by virtual box.

Just in case: My host system is Windows 10

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If the .dvi file was deleted, how are we supposed to know how?

Comment: Thats the problem... I don't have any more information for you because Virtual Box doesn't give me an Error message or sth like that. The VM boots as normal and there are no problems with the guest system itself. But I am not able to edit the .vdi file because it just disappears the moment I first boot the machine. Is this some kinda bug or intended by virtual box?

Comment: Is it possible that it is just in-use and locked?

Comment: Nope... the vm is shut down.

Comment: What do you mean by "disappears"? Doesn't `vboxmanage` find it?

Comment: I cannot find it via the explorer (I also tried to show the hidden files) and I cannot find it via `VBoxManage.exe`.

Comment: To modify the file I would have used the command: `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox> VBoxManage.exe modifymedium "C:\Users\uname\VirtualBox VMs\Linux\Linux.vdi" --resize 25000`

Comment: Look at the configuration file of the VM - the vdi file might be somewhere else. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc Do you mean the logfiles of the VM or the configuration file of VirtualBox itself?

Comment: I mean the XML settings file that should have the `.vbox` file extension. I'm not using VirtualBox so don't have one on hand, but if you wish I can have a look at yours if you post it.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've read myself through the `.vbox` file and found the place where the .vdi was. It's a bit weird... during my first installation I chose the .vdi from my downloads folder and it got copied into the `VirtualBox Vms` folder but now it's just using the .vdi file directly from my Downloads folder. I think that my problem is solved so far. Regards @harrymc !

Comment: I tried to resume the comments below, so this post will have an answer. You may edit it any way you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resuming the comments on this post:

The `vdi` file seemed to be missing because it wasn't in the expected location.

In such a case, the best place to look for it is in the the XML settings file
of the virtual machine, which has the .vbox file extension.

Comment: `$ locate '*.vdi'` could help as well.